# Excel vba button to paste data from one cell into another cell using date criteria

Tags: vba, excel, date, copy-paste

Somewhat new to VBA excel.  I've spent a good 4 days trying to figure this out and playing around with the code and I'm finally reaching out for help.

The gist of what I'm trying to do is use a button that when clicked it takes data that has already been generated and sits in cell L11.  The way the data is supposed to flow is by day in a month.  When data is entered in L11, the day changes each entry. So when I push the button, I'd like the code to say - based on the day (already generated) in cell L8, take the data in L11 and cut and paste it under Sheet2 and column for that date.

I've built the following code that moves the data from L11 to sheet 2 cell A2 and then add the data to the next line on sheet2 if data already exists, but to make what I'm trying to do even faster, I'd like to have the code know what date is in L8 and find that date in a column on sheet2 and paste it under that date while removing the copied data from sheet1:

```
Sub copypastetosheets2()

    For Each cell In Range("L8:L8")
    If cell.Value = "Monday, April 15" Then
        Range("L11:L11").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("sheet2").Select
        Range("A2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("sheet1").Select
        Range("L11").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Sheets("sheet2").Select
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown, copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Sheets("sheet1").Select
        Range("L11").Select
```

I've also used this code on a different button which works and does what I'd like it to do, but it still doesn't recognize the date and to put it in a different column:

```
Sub copypastetosheets()
Sheets("sheet1").Range("L11").Copy


With Sheets("April 15").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("L11:L20").ClearContents
End With

End Sub
```

Don't mind the Sheets("April 15").... I was using that while I was testing.  This code works well, but the only thing holding me back is the recognition of the date.  If it knew to look at the date as changing variable and then based on that specific date pasted the data from L11 on Sheet1 under 1 of the 30 or 31 columns in accordance to that date, I'd be done for now :)

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Dave

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Great job trying to fix together some code. I have a couple thoughts that I will organize in two separate comments in order to maintain some organization and avoid making things confusing.

Comment: First: There is alot of unecessary commands that is making your code appear very cluttered. You really don't need a `for` loop since you are interracting with only one cell. instead, use `If Sheets(1).Cells(8, 12).Value = DateValue("Apr 15, 2018") Then`. This will cut out a line and set your coordinate as well as determine the value you need.

Comment: Second: The use of `.select` can behave erratically and is not a good idea to rely on. Similar to the first point, the use of `Sheets(*sheet name*).Cells(*A1 (sor soemthing similar*).Value` is much more reliable. You can copy data into a cell doing the same thing without having to change the sheet that is active. For example, `Sheets("sheet2").Cells("A2").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Cells("L11").Value`. This line would eliminate almost 10 lines of code.

Comment: Lastly: I am having a hard time understanding what you want copied and where you want it to end up. do you want data from L11 to be sent to A2 and thats it? is there a need to append data in A3? or just overwrite A2 everytime you run the script? Overall, you are on the right track and you have made some good progress for someone who is just beginning to learn VBA, I would recommend the use of some form of visual aid or clarification on the objective of the script before I can try to help troubleshoot what is not working for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response.  Regarding the DateValue function.... By entering ("Apr 15, 2018") next to DateValue, does that mean the action of the vba is going to specifically look for that date?  What I'm hoping for that part of the code to read is cell L8 in Sheet1 and return with the data in L11 pasting it under that specific date in Sheet2.  I have 31 columns in Sheet2.  Each labeled by day, i.e. day 1 (April 1), day 2 (April 2), etc... If the code says "If cell L8 in sheet1 says April 10, enter data from cell L11 under the column with April 10.

Comment: in sheet2." Basically my hope is that the code can say based on the date in L8, take data from L11, remove it from sheet1 and paste it under the specific date column in sheet2.  Hope this makes sense and yes I do need to learn more about how to explain my understanding this.  Thank you as well for the compliments :)

Comment: When a date is placed in a cell, and formatting has not been set, the application, oftentimes recognizes it as a date (as long as you follow common dating formats) if this is done so, then excel recognizes it as a numerical value, not necessarily a string. Now if you are just putting in `"April 15"`, then you will need to treat it as a string and in which case, just remove `DateValue()` and use `"April 15"` this is unusual though as you are designating the date in the script. why do you want a static date in the script? It would be more useful to have the value being referenced on the sheet.

Comment: What is the range you are working on in sheet1? what cells will have data? does the number of rows stay the same? or do they change?

Comment: Forgive my way of explaining this because I think we are on the same page but my lingo is not in tune... Hopefully this explains it... I designated cell L8 as a cell to generate a date from a vlookup formula which is this: VLOOKUP(K8,A28:B58,2,FALSE). That array has the dates of April 1 all the way to April 30. Once the user designates which date they want in L8, they move on to the step of generating data for L11.  When L11 is completed by the user and it has the data they want, the purpose to the above coding is to use a button that reads the date in L8 and move the L11 data under the

Comment: In otherwords, the user inputs the date, and clicks a button. the data that is stored in cell L11 is then stored in sheet2 under the column that is the matching date of L8 in sheet1?

Comment: proper date in Sheet2.  The second code I put in original post executes the action of cutting the data from L11 Sheet1 and pastes it in Sheet2 A2.  The only reason I designated A2 in Sheet2 was because I was trying to get the code work.  Now that I have it working, what didn't know was how to get the code to read the date in L8 and then move it to column B, C, D, E, etc... based on the date that I have in those columns.... I hope this makes sense... crossing my fingers :)

Comment: correct... on what you stated

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Given what you have told me, here is a pretty basic method, for the dates, use `Month day`. For example L8 = `April 3`.

```
Sheet2
April 1   April 2   April 3   April 4   April 5   ...
                    Data is
                    copied
                    here
```

I hope I understand you properly. this will find the matching date in sheet2, copy the data over and delete the data in L8.

```
Option Explicit

Dim x As Integer

Sub Button1_Click()

x = 1

'this will find the column that matches the date and stores that as the copy location.
While Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, x).Value <> Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L8")
    x = x + 1
Wend


'this portion copies the data to the designated coordinates found by the first portion and delete the information from L8 and L11.
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, x).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L11").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L8").Value = ""


End Sub
```

Because L11 has a formula in it, you don't want to delete the cell. Change the formula in it to be this: `=IF(L8 <> "", VLOOKUP(K8,A28:B58,2,FALSE), "")`

This formula will make L11 appear blank as long as L8 has no data in it.

Comment: Updated the code a little, i neglected to think about L11 having a formula in it. I am assuming you don't want to have to add in a new copy of the formula every time you want to run the script.

Comment: would it be a appropriate to post my worksheet here for you to see?  so you can see what I'm trying to accomplish?  Turns out that I'm neglecting to mention other codes I've already built...

Comment: [This might answer you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15821/stack-overflow-etiquette-for-sharing-files-and-resources)  I have no problem looking at an .xlsx version.